# Unable to call another action from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build a simple ASP.net MVC application.

My Controller Looks like below.

```
namespace CustomerReadAndLoad.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Customer/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult LoadCustomer()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DisplayCustomer()
        {
            Customer obj = new Customer();
            obj.ID = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Form["CuatomerID"]);
            obj.Name = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["CuatomerName"]);
            obj.Amount = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Form["CuatomerAmount"]);
            return View(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

I trying to Include the action DisplayCustomer in LoadCustomerView like below

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>   
  <head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>LoadCustomer</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
    <form action ="DisplayCustomer" method ="post">
      Welcome to Customer management System<br />
      Enter the below details <br />
      Customer ID :- <input type="text" name = "CuatomerID" /><br />
      Customer Name :- <input type="text" name = "CuatomerName" /><br />
      Customer Amount :- <input type="text"  name = "CuatomerAmount" /><br />
      <input type ="button"  value="ClickHere" />
    </form>
 </div>
```

I am unable to move to the view DisplayCustomer once i click Submit Button.

Comment: change the type of the input to sumbmit and the action of form to "/Customer/DisplayCustomer"

Comment: You might wanna look into HTML helpers too. They will save you loads of trouble if you learn them now instead of when you application starts crying at you. (eg @using(Html.BeginForm()){ }, @Html.EditorFor()) Just a heads up. It's not 100% required but you'll come back to SO a lot and people will tell you that over and over if you dont start using them asap :) (PS I wrote the examples in Razor format because it's the only format I've used and that I'm comfortable with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>   
  <head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>LoadCustomer</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
    <%using(Html.BeginForm("DisplayCustomer", "Customer", FormMethod.Post)){%>
      Welcome to Customer management System<br />
      Enter the below details <br />
      Customer ID :- <input type="text" name = "CuatomerID" /><br />
      Customer Name :- <input type="text" name = "CuatomerName" /><br />
      Customer Amount :- <input type="text"  name = "CuatomerAmount" /><br />
      <button type ="submit">"ClickHere"</button>        
    <%}%>
 </div>
```